# Using the Webform2PDF pdf generation doesn't properly replace tokens, but only when emailed

Tags: webforms

For example, the token `[submission:values:identification_information:first_name]` is blank in the emailed PDF that gets sent out when submitted, but if I go to the "Results" screen in the CMS, and generate the PDF for a particular submission, the above token is properly replaced with the first name submitted on the document.

Why is this not replaced in the emailed version properly?

This is using modules:

- **Webform** 7.x-4.1
- **Webform 2 PDF** 7.x-3.2

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport and should be posted in appropriate issue queue, not here.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's a bug or just my stupidity in development. I'll move to the issue queue, if that is appropriate. :)

Comment: Expecting tokens to work is perfectly normal, nothing stupid in it, and if they only work in one place and not another, it is a bug. No stupidity on your part, or at least none I can see. And Webform had it's share of token related bugs in it's history.